# R | Changing element in a column based on a condition in another column

Tags: r

This might be a basic question so apologies beforehand. I have a database with following columns

```
Name   Subject   Marks   Check
Mark   English   45      P
Susan  English   23      F
Gerald Math      33      P
```

I want to add 10 to value in column 'Marks' if Check == 'F'. There are many such rows so I don't want to apply a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use a simple arithmetic approach to update

```
df$Marks <- with(df, (Check == 'F') * 10 + Marks)
```

---

Or create a logical condition in `base R` and do the assignment

```
i1 <- df$Check == 'F'
df$Marks[i1] <- df$Marks[i1] + 10
```

-output

```
df
#    Name Subject Marks Check
#1   Mark English    45     P
#2  Susan English    33     F
#3 Gerald    Math    33     P
```

---

Or in `data.table` way, the assignment operation is more simple as the general syntax of data.table is `[i, j, by]` where `i` can be integer index or logical condition.  Here, we specify the logical condition (`Check == 'F'`), specify the `j`  (`Marks + 10`) and assign (`:=`) it to the same column.  The original data.frame is converted to `data.table` with `setDT`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Check == 'F', Marks := Marks + 10]
```

The evaluation happens from left to right i.e. first it converts to data.table (`setDT`), evaluates the `i`, do the assignment on the expression (`Marks + 10`) on the 'Marks' column

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      mutate(Marks = case_when(Check == 'F' ~ Marks + 10L, TRUE ~ Marks))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("Mark", "Susan", "Gerald"), Subject = c("English", 
"English", "Math"), Marks = c(45L, 23L, 33L), Check = c("P", 
"F", "P")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ifelse()`:

```
#Base R sol
df$Marks <- ifelse(df$Check=='F',df$Marks+10,df$Marks)
```

Output:

```
    Name Subject Marks Check
1   Mark English    45     P
2  Susan English    33     F
3 Gerald    Math    33     P
```